# A Mathematica program to output planar partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics

I'd like to have a Mathematica program to output planar partitions for small values.  I seem to remember once writing such a program years ago using a program that appeared in an IEEE journal from the 1960's, but I can't locate the article and can't find the program.  Does anyone have any ideas?
By planar partition I mean exactly what is  given in the first answer to my question, namely:  "a two-dimensional array of integers that are non-increasing both from left to right and top to bottom 
          and that add up to a given number n."

Comment: The [Matematica stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) could be more fruitful. One place to start would be`SortBy[DeleteDuplicates[
  Map[Sort, Map[Total, SetPartitions[Table[1, {n}]], {2}]]], 
 N[Last[#]] &]` (needs `Combinatorica`), which gives you a list of unique partitions of the integer $n$. Then maybe a recursive `Module` which partitions each list entry further, then combines them into matrices?

Comment: My guess is that the O.P. wants a Mathematica program that will compute all plane partitions of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this software suite](http://www.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/software/ergosum/RISC/Omega.html) is the answer to your prayers (and then some). (to give credit: Axel Riese's Omega package).

Answer (score 0):

The unadorned term "planar partition" does not have an unambiguous meaning. One
possible meaning is described in an article in Mathworld entitled [Plane partition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlanePartition.html):

---

[image]

          

<sup>"...a two-dimensional array of integers $n_{i,j}$ that are nonincreasing both from left to right and top to bottom</sup>


          

<sup>and that add up to a given number $n$."</sup>

---

The OP seeks

> to output planar partitions for small values

If you could specify (1) what is the input, (2) what is a "planar partition,"
and (3) for small values of what parameter, then perhaps someone can help.

Comment: I believe the OP does mean plane partitions.

Comment: Removed my incorrect guesses as to the OP's intent.